# Link to Another Blog Post from Within Modal Window

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, blog, hyperlink

I have a simple blog on my internal development site which has two posts.  I use JavaScript on a custom application page to launch the Post.aspx?Id=3 page in a modal window.  Works great.  The only item on that post is a link to a different post, which i want to show in the same modal dialog window.

In Word (or the SharePoint UI) i try to set the target of the link i added to _self.  This does not work.  In fact, none of the options work and upon further inspection of the produced HTML code, the "target" tag is not even in the link.  If i manually add it by editing the html in the SharePoint edit post window, it doesn't show after saving.

No matter what i do, the "target" tag is removed.  How can i link to another blog post from within a modal window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target attribute is modified by SP.UI.Dialog to get the behaviour it thinks is the right one.

The way you can control how links behave in a SharePoint Dialog is by specifying `rel` attribute on your link. In your case you want `sp_DialogLinkInternal` like this:

```
<a href="/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=1" rel="sp_DialogLinkInternal">Link to post 1 (open in same dialog, if any)</a
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much.